# What happened to the kandra, koloss, and Marsh in the end?

Tags: mistborn, cosmere

Towards the end of book 3 of the Mistborn trilogy, *The Hero of Ages*, what happens to the last of the Lord Ruler's Hemalurgic creations?

There are the few kandra, such as KanPaar, who

> refused to obey the First Generation's order to return to their mistwraith forms.

There are the few koloss, led by Human, who

> managed to reach the location of the atium stash, albeit not before it was all gone. (In fact, there was a whole army of koloss outside, but I'm not sure if they survived the scorching heat of that final sunrise.)

And finally, there's Marsh, the last Inquisitor, whom I believe isn't mentioned again after

> he kills Elend.

What happens to all of these at the very end of the book, when

> both Preservation and Ruin are dead and Sazed takes up their power to remake the world? Is there any place for these creatures in that brave new world? Do they turn back into normal humans as everything the Lord Ruler did is undone?

Comment: Related, but not dupe: [What is the fate of the Koloss?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/20953/38235)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Their fates are slowly revealed over the course of the next series, the *Wax and Wayne* books.  The upshot is, most of them were underground, and therefore did survive.

- The kandra

  > Once he was done reorganizing, Harmony guided someone back into the kandra homeland caves and started putting spikes back into bodies.  A majority of the kandra, including two characters we are familiar with, TenSoon and MeLaan, survive with some basic holes in their memory, due to the spikes being gone so long.  Of the rebel kandra, no mention is ever made again, so possible they were left out of this rescue.  Kandra show up explicitly again in *Shadows of Self*, but they're around before that if you're looking.
- The koloss

  > Most of the Koloss were incinerated, but Human and his band were underground.  Per Word of Sanderson, Harmony took pity on them and altered them to be able exist on their own.  They are only directly seen in a short story (published first in a *Mistborn Adventure Game* supplement, then in *Arcanum Unbounded*), titled *Allomancer Jak and the Pits of Eltania*, and haven't yet shown up in the main series of books.  The story contains enough pulp to start a paper business, but according to the snarky footnotes the depiction of koloss is close enough to reality.  Koloss have gender now and can have babies, although these offspring are definitely human, yet pick up some koloss traits like skin-tone, strength, and temperament (leading to the term koloss-blooded).  They also have a little more self-awareness, although still fairly violent, and they keep a basic tribal society.  True full koloss are still made through Hemalurgy, using old preserved spikes.  They seemingly only convert volunteers this way, whether their children grown or a rare outsider, and send away any koloss-blooded adults that refuse this.
- Marsh

  > Marsh I think is the only creature that wasn't explicitly underground, but either he made it to a cave or his abilities let him survive.  He reappears at the end of *Alloy of Law*, perfectly fine after centuries.  Per the author, he still has that bag of loose atium Ruin had him grab from the kandra, and he has enough abilities to use it to Compound his age and stay alive, although we're not given any clues as to when it will run out.